# Ubuntu 19.10 Headphone Audio not working

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, 19.10, headphones

I recently installed Ubuntu 19.10 as dualboot besides Windows 10, and noticed that the headphone audio is not working.

**My Setup:** PC with Speakers on Front Panel, and Headphones on Back Panel of Mainboard.

**Things i have noticed:**

- Headphones are working in Windows 10.
- Headphones are displayed in audio settings when connected, and get removed when disconnected. Output still not working after reconnecting.
- Speakers are working as expected
- When I connect my headphones on the frontpanel where I usually have my speakers connected, my headphones work.
- pavucontrol shows "line out" (which is my headphones) as "plugged in", when playing audio the volume bar under my output device shows that audio is playing.
- alsamixer shows "line out" as not muted and volume is up
- the microphone from my headset that is also connectend on back panel does work

**Things i have tried:**

- `sudo alsa force-reload` and then rebooted PC
- `sudo apt-get remove alsa-base pulseaudio` followed by `sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio` and `sudo alsa force-reload`
- i moved my `~/.config/pulse` to somewhere else, to let pulse create a new config.
- unmuting everything in alsamixer

Any help would be very much apreciated, pls dont go hard on me, I am new to Ubuntu and Linux in general. Thank you!

Comment: Did it work before? Try, with the phones plugged in, the command "alsactl restore".

Comment: Hi @vanadium no, in ubuntu my headphones never worked. I ran "alsactl restore" but sadly that didn't change anything for me. I just switched my headphones to the front panel, where my speakers are connected, and the headphones worked. So the problem is, that there is no audio coming out of my back panel from the mainboard.

Comment: Okay, I don't know wtf happened, but I just switched from windows10 to ubuntu and for some reason my headphone audio is working atm.